# .net core Linux app screw up keypad input

Tags: linux, debian, .net-core, putty

I use PuTTY to connect to my Debian box.

If I have a `console.readline` I the application I cannot use the keypad to input numbers.

E.g. 1 is received as "**Oq**" and 2 as "**Or**"

Not problem using the "normal" number keys.

[image]

My .net core code:

```
Imports System
Module Program
Sub Main(args As String())
    Console.Writeline("Please type 1 from numpad:")
   Dim str as string = Console.Readline
   Console.Writeline("You typed: " & str)
End Sub
End Module
```

Is it an issue with  .net core or PuTTY?

I've tried playing around with the settings in PuTTY (Terminal\Keyboard\Function keys and keypad) but it didn't change anything.

I don't have the problem using the keypad in the shell, only in the .net core app.

If I use a keyboard directly connected to the Debian box I don't have the problem either.

Comment: I understand it's now an .net core issue, but I live the question as it is if anyone find themselves in the same situation. I never ran into this problem until running the .net core console apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I tried some different Google search approaches and this time I found something:

[image]